# Drawing a double line

Tags: rules

I went to create a horizontal double line that fills the page after some words. The code

```
\newcommand{\raisedrule}[2][0em]{\leaders\hbox{\rule[#1]{1pt}{#2}}\hfill}
```

obtain from [LaTeX rule filling the line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553392/latex-rule-filling-the-line) does most of what I want, but I want the line to be a double line (ie. ======) instead of a single line (ie. --------).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Leave a little gap and draw another one? Welcome! You've not exactly given us much to go on: why can't you just draw one and then another one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options, depending on your usage:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\newcommand{\doublerule}[1][.4pt]{%
  \noindent
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[.7ex]{\linewidth}{#1}}%
  \rule[.3ex]{\linewidth}{#1}}

\newcommand{\raisedrule}[2][0pt]{%
  \leaders
  \hbox{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[#1]{1pt}{#2}}%
    \rule[\dimexpr#1+.4ex]{1pt}{#2}%
  }\hfill}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]%
\raisedrule{.4pt}

\doublerule

\lipsum*[2]%
\raisedrule[.3ex]{1pt}

\doublerule[1pt]

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Of course, other fine-tuning is possible.

Comment: the separation between the two lines is slightly different between the partial-line and full-line versions.  i think they should have the same separation.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Agreed.